# Spring framework: what happens when you inject a Java bean into another Java bean but they have different scopes

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I'm new to Java and Spring framework programming.
Please consider the following two Java files:

```
//AccountService.java

package org.mycompany.accountManagement

@Path("/bankaccount")
@Component
@Scope("session")
public class AccountService
{
  private Depositer myDepositer;

  @Autowired
  pubilc AccountService( Depositer depositer )
  { 
    myDepositer = depositer; 
  }
}
```

---

```
//Depositer.java

package org.mycompany.accountManagement

@Component
@Scope("request")
public class Depositer
{
  public void deposit(){ System.out.println("Depositing..."); }
}
```

The class AccountService is instantiated only once for a given HTTP session. When it is instantiated, a Depositer object was also instantiated and was kept by AccountService as a private variable. Since the lifetime of this AccountService object persists throughout the HTTP session, I suppose the Depositor object that it keeps is used throughout the session. However, the scope of the Depositor class was supposed to be "request," i.e., instantiation for every request... I'm confused here, is a new Depositer object instantiated for every request? Or is the same Depositor object used throughout the session?

Comment: In spring, request scoped bean is used in HTTP request life-cycle. For each and every HTTP request, new instance of bean is created and is alive for complete HTTP request life-cycle. What I'd do is put some logging statement in Depositer constructor and see how many times it is being instantiated when requests are made or when new sessions are being created. This will give you an idea.

Comment: @Path("/bankaccount") is per request, session scope is irrelevant here

Answer (score 0):

Spring uses Proxy pattern internally to solve this and create new instance for request scope bean inside session scoped bean, you know spring has access to every `HttpServletRequest` and you can even inject it in your class if you want. so it wraps the session scope bean with a proxy and when you reference request scope bean from the containing session scope bean if it is a new `HttpServletRequest` it will create new instance but if it is the same `HttpServletRequest` it returns the existing request scope bean.